# MySQL INSERT BEFORE TRIGGER Fails?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm running MySQL 5.1.48 on Windows XP and the following trigger test doesn't work:

```
-- Drop the old table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ikasan01`.`ikasanwiretap`;

-- Create
CREATE TABLE  `ikasan01`.`ikasanwiretap` (
 `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ModuleName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `FlowName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `ComponentName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `EventId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `PayloadId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `PayloadContent` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `CreatedDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `UpdatedDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `Expiry` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- In order to use now() as a DEFAULT value on a datetime column we
have to do it via a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER
CREATE TRIGGER defaultUpdateDateTime
BEFORE INSERT ON ikasanwiretap FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.UpdatedDateTime = now();

-- Test the trigger
insert into IkasanWiretap (ModuleName, FlowName, ComponentName,
EventId, PayloadId, PayloadContent, CreatedDateTime, Expiry) values
('3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', now(), now());
```

On my trigger test I still get the MySQL server stating that the UpdateDateTime has no default value.

I've tried just about everything at my disposal so I thought I'd ask you helpful lot ;)  Any ideas?

Cheers,
Martijn

PS:  X-posted on the London Java User Group and the Ikasan EIP Mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the trigger is started after the "not null" constraints are verified.

Remove the "not null" on UpdatedDateTime.

Comment: Hi pascal, that certainly does solve it yes although I'm a little surprised that the constraint is checked first.  If anyone else has further thoughts on this then please do share!

Comment: Yes, it's strange. I would have assumed that the `before` trigger occurs before the constraints validation...

Comment: I understand this is the accepted answer, however can anyone further confirm this restriction? I'm just looking for certainty (*checking MySQL docs now*)